# comunicação entre uma console web com a base de dados da firebase

Tags: php, html, firebase

Posso ler os dados da base de dados dp firebase através de uma console web.
 Essa procura dos dados pode ser feita  através de uma  pagina HTML sabendo que os dados já se encontram armazenados na base de dados?

OBS: Esses dados foram trave de um App

Comment: É possível com [NodeJS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=pt-br) ou [firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) para PHP

Comment: Você pode usar a API REST para isso https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/